# setting accountexpires date with PHP and LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

I'm having trouble setting the 'accountexpires' and wondered if anyone knows a way around it, I believe it's because I have a 18 digit number. I have a form where someone sets a date, I need to set the account to expire then, if I provide the number as a hardcoded string it works, but I cannot convert the finished calculation to a string. Anyone know any way around this? thanks.

```
<?php
$currentTimeUnix = 1442383989; //this will vary depending on user's input
$secondsBetween1601and1970 = 11644473600;
$timesAdded = $currentTimeUnix + $secondsBetween1601and1970;// comes to 13086857589
$nanoseconds = $timesAdded * 10000000; //comes to 130868575890000000
echo $nanoseconds; //displays 1.3086857589E+017
echo (string)$nanoseconds; //displays 1.3086857589E+017
echo strval($nanoseconds); //displays 1.3086857589E+017
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is kind of bad with large numbers but sprintf can help. try:

```
echo sprintf( '%018.0f', $nanoseconds );
-> 130868575890000000
```

Alternatively you change the "precision" setting where `precision` is described:

> **precision integer**
>
> ```
> The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
> ```

```
ini_set("precision",20);
echo $nanoseconds;
-> 130868575890000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. Been testing true out the net but nothing worked until i stumbled on this solution:

```
$expiredate = strtotime($values["expires"]);
$currentTimeUnix = $expiredate;
$secondsBetween1601and1970 = 11644473600;
$timesAdded = $currentTimeUnix + $secondsBetween1601and1970;
$nanoseconds = $timesAdded * 10000000;
$expires = sprintf('%018.0f',$nanoseconds);
```